# How do I use a filter to select a selected column from a table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an employee table that contains like 20 columns and I want to create a filter so I could filter like 4 to 5 different columns at once
for example, if I want to filter for Bio-data when I filter for bio-data I should see only columns related to bio-data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.